# Hazelcast Evicts Ojbects Too Quickly from Hibernate Second Level Cache

Tags: hibernate, hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast as my second-level cache provider for Hibernate. What I am seeing is that cache-entries are getting evicted every 60 seconds, regardless of the settings in hazelcast.xml.

My hazelcast.xml config:

```
<map name="default">
    <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
    <backup-count>1</backup-count>
    <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
    <time-to-live-seconds>21600</time-to-live-seconds>
    <max-idle-seconds>1800</max-idle-seconds>
    <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>
    <max-size policy="PER_NODE">10000</max-size>
    <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
    <min-eviction-check-millis>100</min-eviction-check-millis>
    <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.PutIfAbsentMapMergePolicy</merge-policy>
    <cache-deserialized-values>INDEX-ONLY</cache-deserialized-values>
    <statistics-enabled>true</statistics-enabled>
</map>
<map name="*.Member">
    <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
    <backup-count>0</backup-count>
    <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
    <time-to-live-seconds>21600</time-to-live-seconds>
    <max-idle-seconds>1800</max-idle-seconds>
    <eviction-policy>LFU</eviction-policy>
    <max-size policy="PER_NODE">4000</max-size>
    <statistics-enabled>true</statistics-enabled>
</map>
```

My `hibernate.cache.region.factory_class` is set to `HazelcastLocalCacheRegionFactory`.

By turning on all the logging I could find, I can see the first transaction issuing SQL to load the `Member` object. Subsequent transactions do not issue SQL; rather, they find the object in the second-level cache as expected. However, after 60 seconds a cache-miss is reported (even though time-to-idle is 1800 seconds).  I can see this by sending the same request every 5 seconds and watching the logs - after 60 seconds, I see fresh SQL issued to reload the item. There is never any indication from Hibernate or Hazelcast that the objects are being evicted.

I also tried removing the wildcard from the map name and using the FQCN.

Loggers are

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.sql" level="DEBUG" />
<logger name="org.hibernate.jdbc" level="DEBUG" />
<logger name="org.hibernate.cache" level="DEBUG" />
<logger name="org.hibernate.event" level="TRACE" />
<logger name="com.hazelcast" level="TRACE" />
```

I am using

- Spring Boot 2.1.1
- Hibernate 5.3.7
- Hazelcast 3.11
- hazelcast-hibernate53 3.1.0

Comment: How many Hazelcast nodes do you have? Did you restart all the nodes with the above map configurations? There is no global map configuration, nodes apply their own configuration to the partitions they own. It might be possible that some of your nodes have 60secs max-idle config. Can you confirm?

Comment: I was only using one node for these tests.  In production, all nodes run the exact same binaries and configs.

Comment: You don't have more than 4000 entry, right, since you also limited entry size to 4000 per member?

Comment: Yeah, during my test only one Member object was loaded.

Comment: @ken-delong, after reading the documentation & checking the code, a quick note: If you check the README, it says that only max-size & TTL supported when using HazelcastLocalCacheRegionFactory. Please see the last paragraph in this section: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-hibernate/blob/master/README.md#hazelcastlocalcacheregionfactory

Comment: It's normal not to see any eviction log in Hazelcast since data is not stored in Hazelcast in this mode, it's stored locally on that node. I'm still checking why its evicted after 60 sec.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same problem. Every 60 seconds `CleanupService` runs `cleanup` in `LocalRegionCache` that removes the entries with ttl > 0 from cache.

It could be bug in [hazelcast-hibernate53](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-hibernate5). I reported it as an [issue](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-hibernate5/issues/55).

EDIT:
It was a bug. It is fixed in hazelcast-hibernate5 1.3.2.